# How to get the URL of a sitemap that contains a certain post?

Tags: cache, sitemap

I am searching for a way to "detect" in which sitemap a post is located in but I cannot find any solution to this problem, nor does any SEO plugin or Cache plugin provide any way or wrapper function to return this?

Essentially I'm looking for a function that takes a $post_id or a $post object and can return a sitemap URL in which that post is located or an array of sitemaps (if it shows up in multiple sitemaps).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wonder why  you need this. Is this for few ids or many? This seems to be similar to find the page number of the post id: `wp-sitemap-posts-post-{page-number}.xml`. Probably no pretty/easy general solutions here to find it: loop alot, cache alot, fetch and parse alot or dig alot into SQL,  choose one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it using this simple query

```
<?php

$chunks=array_chunk(
  get_posts([
    'fields'=>'ids',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'post_type'=>[$post->post_type],
    'orderby'=>'ID',
    'order'=>'ASC'
  ]),
  wp_sitemaps_get_max_urls('post')
);

foreach($chunks as $key => $chunk) {
  if(!in_array($post->ID,$chunk)) continue;

  var_dump(get_sitemap_url('posts',$post->post_type,$key + 1));
  break;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know there is wp_sitemaps_get_max_urls() that can tell you how many there are in a sitemap.

Comment: Nope, you don't get it. It tells you what's the limit of urls per sitemap.